# JButton color not changing

Tags: java, swing, colors, jbutton

I'm trying to create a very basic java GUI program that solves a Boggle board.
 
It uses a recursive DFS. What I want to happen is for the background color of the button(I used buttons simply because they are already squares) from yellow to red as the letter gets "marked" and back to yellow when they are "unmarked." 
If I comment out the last line that recharges it back to yellow, and the method which uses Thread.sleep() to delay the program, it works as intended leaving them all as red, but if I uncomment only the delay method, it does not update in real time and all of the backgrounds change to red when the program finishes running.
If I uncomment the line that changes it back to yellow, it stays yellow the entire time.

I can't figure out how to get the button to switch to red and back to yellow in real time.

```
if(r+1 != bBoard.length && c+1 != bBoard.length && !bBoard[r+1][c+1].equals(""))
    {
        String temp = bBoard[r][c];
        bBoard[r][c] = "";
        boardLabel[r][c].setBackground(Color.RED);
        if(dictionary.contains(word) && word.length() > 2)
        {
            wordList.add(word);
            delayProgram();

        }
        depthFirstSearch(bBoard, r+1, c+1, word);
        bBoard[r][c] = temp;
        boardLabel[r][c].setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    }
```

Comment: "in real time" means that the code to change the button's color exists within an event listener such as an ActionListener. We have no idea if this is so based on this code snippet.  Also, never put the GUI thread to sleep. If you need a delay in a Swing GUI, then use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels the code is not in an action listener, the buttons are never actually used as buttons, I only made them buttons for formatting sake. the color is changed inside of a loop that is called by a different button, whose color never changes

Comment: So is this code called on creation of the object? Hard to say what is going on based on our limited views of your problem and your code, and you will want to consider [edit]ing your question and show us more pertinent code as code-formatted text, a [mcve] to be exact (please read the link).

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you have bunch (table) of yellow buttons. You loop through them and change their color to red for a while before changing back to yellow and moving to the next button, is that correct?

Comment: @MatheM yes. it is simulating a boggle board, and it does a dfs search, where it will go from the top left, add the first letter to a string, then check the letter to its right by adding it to the same string and checking against a treeset of dictionary words. I want the letters that the string currently holds to be red, and then change back to yellow when they aren't being used anymore. but they stay yellow the entire time. I changed all the buttons to labels and still get the same behavior.

Comment: *"(I used buttons simply because they are already squares)"* No, they're not. Much the same procedure used to make them square, will also work with other components like `JLabel`. Having said that, if the user ever has need to click on one of the board positions, I'd recommend using a `JButton` over a `JLabel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default your application starts single thread and does all the computation on this thread. When you change color of component it will be redrawn only when the program has spare time to do it, but the program never has spare time because the computation continues.

What you need to do is put the code in this loop to another thread and update the GUI from this second thread.

This is a little working example that should get you started.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ColorfulButtons extends JFrame {

    private JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[5];

    // start the application, this starts the original thread
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ColorfulButtons frame = new ColorfulButtons();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public ColorfulButtons() {
        // create your gui
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 0));

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            JLabel lbl = new JLabel("TEXT");
            add(lbl);
            labels[i] = lbl;
        }

        // start the color changing thread
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                doTheThing();
            }
            // give it a name for debugging
        }, "DoTheThingThread").start();
    }

    private void doTheThing() {
        int index = 0;
        while (true) {
            // put label in final variable so I can use it inside anonymous classes
            final JLabel lbl = labels[index];

            // make label yellow on Event Dispatch Thread
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    lbl.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
                }
            });

            // pause to give the gui time to redraw and process events 
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // make label red on Event Dispatch Thread
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    lbl.setForeground(Color.RED);
                }
            });

            // increment or reset index
            if (index < 5 - 1)
                index++;
            else
                index = 0;
        }
    }
}
```